# .template (dot-template) construction usage

Tags: c++, templates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where and why do I have to put the “template” and “typename” keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)

I've come across a strange segment of code:

```
#include <iostream>

template <int N>
struct Collection {
  int data[N];

  Collection() {
    for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
      data[i] = 0;
    }
  };

  void SetValue(int v) {
    for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
      data[i] = v;
    }
  };

  template <int I>
  int GetValue(void) const {
    return data[I];
  };
};

template <int N, int I>
void printElement(Collection<N> const & c) {
  std::cout << c.template GetValue<I>() << std::endl; /// doesn't compile without ".template"
}

int main() {
  Collection<10> myc;
  myc.SetValue(5);
  printElement<10, 2>(myc);
  return 0;
}
```

It is not compiled without **.template** keyword in *printElement* function. I've never seen this before and I don't understand what is needed for. Trying to remove it, I got a lot of template-related compilation errors. So my question is when such a construction is used? Is it common?

Comment: Just for the record, it's not a `.template` (a single dot-template construct), but two tokens, a dot, followed by the `template` keyword.

It would also have been legal to write `c. template GetValue<I>`. The `template` is tied to the member function `GetValue`, not the dot.

Comment: This question - though being a duplicate - is useful. Just searching template will bring up lots of noise. The "dot-template" phrase is what I found in the end.

Answer (score 80):

`GetValue` is a dependent name, and so you need to explicitly tell the compiler that what follows `c` is a function *template*, not some member data. That is why you need to write `template` keyword to disambiguate this.

Without `template` keyword, the following

```
c.GetValue<I>()  //without template keyword
```

could be interpreted as:

```
//GetValue is interpreted as member data, comparing it with I, using < operator
((c.GetValue) < I) > () //attempting to make it a boolean expression
```

that is, the `<` is interpreted as less-than operator, and `>` is interpreted as greater-than operator. The above interpretation is of course incorrect, as it doesn't make sense, and therefore, would result in compilation error.

For more detail explanation, read the accepted answer here:

- [Where and why do I have to put the "template" and "typename" keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)